# What is the algorithm to divide an area into smaller areas?

Tags: python, image, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

I am designing an autonomous lawn mower. To mow the whole lawn, I first want to divide the area into smaller areas using some algorithm.

For example, if my lawn is of 500 sq-mt, I would like the algorithm to divide it into 20 near rectangular with each rectangle approximately of size 25 sq-mt. I want the algorithm to return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the coordinates of a smaller rectangle. How can I design such an algorithm?

Comment: Knowing that it is 500m^2 is not enough. It could be 1m * 500m or it could be 10m * 50m. The returned rectangles would look very different.

Comment: What are the possible dimensions of the lawn? Is it always rectangular, or can it have more than 4 sides? How many pieces would you like the lawn to be divided into? Does this change with the size of the lawn? Or is it based on a fixed size of 'piece'? What if the lawn is smaller than this size? **What have you tried so far?**

Comment: One approach: let the user specify how many parts vertically (nv) and horizontally (nh). Number of smaller areas will be nv * nh. Start coding. See how it develops. If you're stuck please ask.

Comment: "to divide it into 20 near rectangular" -don't you actually want 'near square' areas, instead of 'near rectangular' areas? you can always divide a large rectangle into as-many-as-you-want smaller rectangles, there's nothing special. However, trying to divide an area into exactly N smaller squares is not always possible, so it is a challenge to pick the dimensions as close as possible to those of a square